# Java file lock use two different streams, same thread

Tags: java, multithreading

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
FileChannel channel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
FileLock lock = channel.tryLock(); // specifically not using lock, 
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
 while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {}
```

Results in **java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException**

I thought this would work as both streams are in same thread/process. However the lock seems to be applied on a stream basis ?

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet which produce the mentioned `OverlappingFileLockException`. The posted snippet produces `java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file`.

Comment: @SubOptimal that code only consumes one process, so it can't produce the error your stated on its own?